UTAUT model in lavaan: "modifier label specified multiple times"
I am trying to perform an UTAUT model with the help of lavaan in Rstudio. In particular testing hypothesis such as:
H2 <- ' 
EE =~ V10+V11+V12
BI =~ V28+V29+V30
BI ~ EE + V43*EE + V45*EE + V43 + V45
           '
fith2 <- sem(model=H2, data=Dats , estimator = "WLSMV", ordered = TRUE, std.lv = TRUE)
summary(fith2, fit.measure = TRUE, standardized=TRUE)

Although it performs the task, Rstudio sends a message that makes me think I am doing something wrong:
    Warning:
lavaan->ldw_parse_model_string():  
   modifier label specified multiple times, overwritten at line 4, pos 20
BI ~ EE + V43*EE + V45*EE + V43 + V45
                   ^

That does mean that the model is ill-defined? Why cannot moderate EE twice with different variables (V43 and V45)?


Why cannot moderate EE twice with different variables (V43 and V45)?

lavaan model syntax is not a formula-class object, it is just a character string that uses a couple of the same operators (e.g., '~' means "is regressed on", + means "and").  An asterisk is not a shortcut for specifying product terms, like you can do in a formula:
~ a*b
## same as
~ a + b + a:b
## see ?formula help page

In lavaan syntax, the asterisk is used to add a label or a fixed/free value to a parameter:
https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax2.html
Edited 27 November:
You can use the colon operator to specify a product term, but only between 1 pair of observed variables at a time:
BI ~ EE + V43 + V45 + V43:EE + V45:EE

However, because EE is a latent variable, there is no way to calculate its product with observed variables like V43 or V45.  The product-indicator approach could help to define an "interaction factor" for each latent product.  Find some example syntax here, provided in the context of using such a model to test invariance.  It uses the semTools::indProd() function mentioned in the error message.
